# x86 offset directive and memory adressing

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-address

I am confused with the use of the offset directive and variable addresses. Here is my code:

```
.model flat,c

.const
FibVals dword 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13
dword 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610

NumFibVals_ dword ($ - FibVals) / sizeof dword
public NumFibVals_

.code
blablabla ...
.
.
.
mov ebx,offset FibVals ;ebx = FibVals
mov esi,[ebp+8] ;esi = i
shl esi,2 ;esi = i * 4
add ebx,esi ;ebx = FibVals + i * 4
mov eax,[ebx] ;Load table value, eax = FibVals[i]
mov edi,[ebp+12]
mov [edi],eax ;Save to 'v1'
.
.
.
end
```

I do not understand why we use an offset directive to reference  the FibVals variable here:

```
mov ebx,offset FibVals ;ebx = FibVals
```

instead of:

```
mov ebx,[FibVals]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `mov ebx,offset FibVals` stores the *address of* `FibVals` while `mov ebx,[FibVals]` stores *what is stored at* `FibVals`. Why? It depends on the program after the line.

Comment: you're right, I will add details of the code

Comment: Also, I thought that FibVals was the address of the first element of the array, like in C an array is in fact a pointer to its first element.

Can't we just do:
              mov ebx, FibVals 
then ?

Comment: You can think of the `[]` as C dereferencing via `*`. So `[FibVals]` is `*FibVals` which would give you the first element and not the address. `offset` is like the `&` operator. As to what `mov ebx, FibVals` does depends on assembler, in your case it seems to be masm and that treats it as `mov ebx, [FibVals]`.

Comment: @jester Thank you very much, now it is clear to me. I did not know that it could depends on which assembler is used.